# Add custom options based on the value of select field in admin

Tags: magento2

Add custom options based on the value of select field in admin.
Hello All,

I want to add dynamic form fields based on the value of the select value in magento 2.3 in admin.

Actually i am working on survey extension and in which i want to implement that if admin select type of question which he is added to "short-answer", then textarea will be shown.

I think for this i need to implement custom options. but what exactly don't get that. So can anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Unable to understand. Can you please explain briefly?

Comment: i want to add custom options on the basis of select value. suppose if i select radio then i will be able to add options. It is basically customisable options. But how can we do programmatically ? can u pls suggest?